# Problem while initializing the repo

Tags: android, git

While initializing the repo to download Android Source Code using the following command -

```
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
```

I'm getting the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pritamn/bin/repo", line 603, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/home/pritamn/bin/repo", line 570, in main
_Init(args)
File "/home/pritamn/bin/repo", line 184, in _Init
_CheckGitVersion()
File "/home/pritamn/bin/repo", line 213, in _CheckGitVersion
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1201, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
```

Can anybody please help me in pin-pointing the exact cause of this error?

Answer (score 1):

You must have git installed for that command to work

Answer (score 1):

Do you have git installed? Make sure it's installed by typing "git" on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder guys.But,even after installing git I get the following - 
    Getting repo ...
    from git://android.git.kernel.org/tools/repo.git
    android.git.kernel.org[0: 149.20.4.77]: errno=Connection timed out
    android.git.kernel.org[0: 149.20.20.141]: errno=Connection timed out
    android.git.kernel.org[0: 199.6.1.176]: errno=Connection timed out
    android.git.kernel.org[0: 130.239.17.12]: errno=Connection timed out
    fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
Does it indicate a problem with my network connection or the git server?

Answer (score 1):

Running on Win7 64bit I had to add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin" to my PATH in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me, you need to `apt-get remove git-core` and re-install it using `apt-get install git-core`.